# Get error HEAT5150 with x64 dll

Tags: wix, heat

I get this error when I have a x64 dll in the folder that I try to harvest

> heat.exe : error HEAT5150: Could not harvest data from a file that was
>   expected  to be a SelfReg DLL:
>   C:\Users\ama\Documents\Projekt\FreePIE\Output\sixense_fak e_x64.dll.
>   If this file does not support SelfReg you can ignore this warning. O
>   therwise, this error detail may be helpful to diagnose the failure:
>   Unable to l oad file:
>   C:\Users\ama\Documents\Projekt\FreePIE\Output\sixense_fake_x64.dll, e
>   rror: 193
>   [C:\Users\ama\Documents\Projekt\FreePIE\BuildTools\build_installer.xm
>   l]

How can I configure heat to support x64 dlls or just add them without doing any checking? 
its just a static c library, my program is not even using it, if the user wants to fake this SDK he copes over the sixense_fake_x64.dll from the install folder to the third party program that is dependent on it.

edit Source code if of any help

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Heat.exe has a number of switches that control harvesting. Run `heat -?` to see a list. The one you want is:

`-sreg    suppress registry harvesting`